# Mockito doThrow on void method with null argument not throwing exception: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, mockito

I am unsure if I have found a bug or if I am just doing it wrong. I am trying to have a mock throw an exception when a method is invoked (relatively easy normally), except the method is of `void` return type, and the object to be passed in (why the error is thrown) is `null`. This can be typed through `isNull()` to compile, but the error is still not thrown.

```
package some.example;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.isNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.reset;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.SessionAwareMessageListener;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {
    @Mock
    private AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageContainer;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpMocks() {
        initMocks(this);

        doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(messageContainer).setupMessageListener(
                isNull(MessageListener.class));
        doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(messageContainer).setupMessageListener(
                isNull(SessionAwareMessageListener.class));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void resetMocks() {
        reset(messageContainer);
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = { IllegalArgumentException.class })
    public void testSetUpQueueConsumerWithNullMessageListener() throws Exception {
        final MessageListener messageListener = null;
        try (final QueueConsumer consumer = new QueueConsumer(messageContainer, messageListener)) {
        } finally {
            verify(messageContainer).setupMessageListener(messageListener);
        }
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = { IllegalArgumentException.class })
    public void testSetUpQueueConsumerWithNullSessionAwareMessageListener() throws Exception {
        final SessionAwareMessageListener<Message> messageListener = null;
        try (final QueueConsumer consumer = new QueueConsumer(messageContainer, messageListener)) {
        } finally {
            verify(messageContainer).setupMessageListener(messageListener);
        }
    }

    public class QueueConsumer implements AutoCloseable {
        private final AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageContainer;

        QueueConsumer(final AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageContainer,
                final SessionAwareMessageListener<? extends Message> messageListener) {
            this(messageContainer);
            this.messageContainer.setupMessageListener(messageListener);
        }

        QueueConsumer(final AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageContainer, final MessageListener messageListener) {
            this(messageContainer);
            this.messageContainer.setupMessageListener(messageListener);
        }

        private QueueConsumer(final AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageContainer) {
            if (messageContainer == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("MessageListenerContainer cannot be null");
            }
            this.messageContainer = messageContainer;
        }

        public void stop() {
            messageContainer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
            stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.21</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8-beta</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**

I added the stripped down real code. I toyed with the code more this morning, and discovered I was using Mockito's `reset()` incorrectly. I thought it would reset the mock to its unverified state, but it also erases the `doThrow()` stubs. I had to change the initialization methods as follows:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUpMocks() {
    initMocks(this);
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUpThrows() {
    doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(messageContainer).setupMessageListener(
            isNull(MessageListener.class));
    doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(messageContainer).setupMessageListener(
            isNull(SessionAwareMessageListener.class));
}
```

Comment: Not sure I didn't test your code, but it looks like "interfaceMock" is not null since it's annotated with @Mock, so your "doSomething" method is NOT called with a null argument.

Comment: You must know that annotating @Mock instanciates a mock derived from your class.

Comment: Make sure your `initMocks` method is annotated `@Before`, not `@BeforeClass`. Also, is `SimpleExample` a class here, and does it have any final methods?

Comment: @Joel you are right. I fixed the example as you said, and it works. So I stripped down the actual code I'm using, and it also works, without a bunch of other function calls and a few verifications. So there must be some interaction somewhere I'm missing in the setup.

Comment: @JeffBowman you hinted at the correct solution. I edited the post to reflect it. I believe you're thinking JUnit with `@Before`, where TestNG uses `@BeforeMethod`. I've been intermittently doing mock setup wrong intermittently and forgetting the correct way when I run into little issues like this. Thanks for your help, @Joel too.

Comment: @FinalDoom In this scenario, you actually do not need to use the reset method.  The reason for this is because JUnit will regard Test annotated method as a new test case.  This means that junit will re-initialize your test class, which includes class state.  It is a mechanism designed to help ensure that test data does not bleed over from one test to another.  Basically, for every Test annotated method, your message container will get re-initialized with an empty mock object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As resolved in the comments and edit: Be careful to note that the [`reset`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#reset(T...)) method resets the mock *entirely*, including both stubs and interactions (the latter for verifications).

As [warned in the Mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17), `reset` is generally a bad sign in your tests: If it comes in the middle of a test method, generally that method should be split up into multiple smaller tests, and if it comes in an `@After` or `@AfterMethod` it means that your test setup is polluting between tests. Keep your mocks in instance fields, not static fields, initialized in a `@Before` (JUnit) or `@BeforeMethod` (TestNG) method to ensure they're fully overwritten before every single test in a test class.

Comment: Good point. I realized once I figured out the problem and rewrote a couple tests to use method local mocks.